# Multinomial multivariate adaptive regression splines MARS

Tags: r, matlab, sas

Does anyone happen to know how to run a MARS model with a multinomial response (0,1,2) in R or other softwares? I have used `earth` package for binomial one with "binomial" family and it works well. However, when it comes to a multinomial response, it seems that there is no option available for that. Any hint will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as 've heard about **`R`** / **`MARS`** integration, Salford Systems has announced earlier in 2015/Q1 an extension to their system to allow users to access `MARS` from **`R`**-session.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

to the best of my knowledge there isn't a multivariate method for the MARS algorithm. one alternative is to fit K binomial MARS models and "scale" the probability predictions using the softmax function.